# What does the Recv-Q values in a Listen socket mean?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, netstat

My program runs in trouble with a `netstat` output like bellow. It cannot receive a packet. What does the Recv-Q value in the first line mean? I see the man page, and do some googling, but no result found.

```
[root@(none) /data]# netstat -ntap | grep 8000
tcp      129      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1526/XXXXX-
tcp        0      0 9.11.6.36:8000          9.11.6.37:48306         SYN_RECV    -
tcp        0      0 9.11.6.36:8000          9.11.6.34:44936         SYN_RECV    -
tcp      365      0 9.11.6.36:8000          9.11.6.37:58446         CLOSE_WAIT  -
tcp      364      0 9.11.6.36:8000          9.11.6.37:55018         CLOSE_WAIT  -
tcp      364      0 9.11.6.36:8000          9.11.6.37:42830         CLOSE_WAIT  -
tcp      364      0 9.11.6.36:8000          9.11.6.37:56344         CLOSE_WAIT  -
tcp        0    364 9.11.6.34:38947         9.11.6.36:8000          FIN_WAIT1   -
tcp      364      0 9.11.6.36:8000          9.11.6.37:52406         CLOSE_WAIT  -
tcp      365      0 9.11.6.36:8000          9.11.6.37:53603         CLOSE_WAIT  -
tcp      364      0 9.11.6.36:8000          9.11.6.37:47522         CLOSE_WAIT  -
tcp      364      0 9.11.6.36:8000          9.11.6.34:48191         CLOSE_WAIT  -
tcp      364      0 9.11.6.36:8000          9.11.6.37:51813         CLOSE_WAIT  -
tcp      364      0 9.11.6.36:8000          9.11.6.34:57789         CLOSE_WAIT  -
tcp      364      0 9.11.6.36:8000          9.11.6.37:34252         CLOSE_WAIT  -
tcp      364      0 9.11.6.36:8000          9.11.6.34:38930         CLOSE_WAIT  -
tcp      365      0 9.11.6.36:8000          9.11.6.37:44121         CLOSE_WAIT  -
tcp      365      0 9.11.6.36:8000          9.11.6.37:60465         CLOSE_WAIT  -
tcp      365      0 9.11.6.36:8000          9.11.6.37:37461         CLOSE_WAIT  -
tcp        0    362 9.11.6.34:35954         9.11.6.36:8000          FIN_WAIT1   -
tcp      364      0 9.11.6.36:8000          9.11.6.37:55241         CLOSE_WAIT  -
```

P.S.
See also at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.linux.networking/PoP0YOOIj70

Comment: What does a simple downvote mean? Any reasons?

Comment: I didn't downvote. But your problem description is terrible. What does "It cannot receive a packet" mean? Is your program trying to receive packets? If so, what is using TCP for? Do you mean that `recv` hangs? Which of those lines has anything to do with your program?

Comment: Thanks David, and sorry for the terrible description. My program(server part) listen on port 8000 for `TCP` connections. It used to be Ok, accept connections, receive packets, send packets. But now, it cannot. I use ``tcpdump`` to capture some packets, found a lot of `Retransmission` from the client part, and `Dup ACK` from the server part. And the `netstat` output are above.

Comment: That's only very slightly helpful. Saying "it cannot" doesn't tell us much. What happens when you try? Does some function return an error? Which function? And what error?

Comment: Sorry David, but there isn't any details here. I use the `boost::asio:: ip:: tcp::acceptor` to `async_accept` connections, it just doesn't call my `AcceptHandler`, no error, no success.

Comment: Your *actual* problem, or at least one of them, is all the CLOSE_WAIT states. These are connections which have been closed by the peer and not yet closed by the local application. This may indicate a bug, e.g. a socket leak, or a failure to recognize and act on end of stream or a socket exception/fatal error.

Comment: @EJP, it has been running into a wrong state. It used to close properly. I am trying to find what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recv-Q is the Receive Queue. It is the number of bytes that are currently in a receive buffer. Upon reading the socket, the bytes are removed from the buffer and put into application memory. If the Recv-Q number gets too high, packets will be dropped because there is no place to put them.

More info here [netstat](http://khaidoan.wikidot.com/linux-netstat)

Comment: Thanks @Upsampled, but what that mean in a `LISTEN` state at the first line, does that mean it has some connect requests to accept?

Comment: And in a LISTEN state, the Recv-Q means the count of connections to be accept in kernel version 3.10.x

Comment: That is a possibility. Are you sure you are accepting the connection after the initial attempt?

Comment: Thanks @Upsampled, I will try to find that out.

Comment: The Recv-Q number cannot 'get too high', as it is limited by the size of the socket receive buffer. When the socket receive buffer fills, TCP advertises a zero receive window to the sender, which stops sending. There is no packet dropping.

Comment: @EJP, haven't realized that. A TCP packet cannot be simply dropped.

Comment: @Morris That's not correct either. Incoming SYNs can be ignored, for example, if the backlog queue is full. However this answer should not have been accepted.

Comment: @EJP, flow control mechanisms like zero window are not active on a socket in the `Listen' TCP state. So the buffer can only be filling with SYNs, correct?

Comment: What I really want to know is the meaning of Recv-Q in the LISTEN state, and I got the answer. And the Recv-Q value doesn't grow larger than 129 according to the `backlog`.